# How to write test case to match a string with Id in Jest and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I want to write a test case to match a string in jest. I have written the code but if I am passing wrong ID still my test is passed. Can someone help me in that ?

Here is my code -

Component code -

```
<Typography id="showingRecords" component="div" className={classes.showRecord}>
              Showing <span className={classes.showRecordText}>6 actions</span>
            </Typography>
```

My test case -

```
test('should render a showing record section', () => {
        actionPlanProps["data"] = actionPlanData.data;
        const render = shallow(<ActionPlanCardComponent {...actionPlanProps} />);
        expect(
            render
                .find("#showingRecordsws").first()
                ).toBeDefined();
    });
```

If I am passing any wrong id still It is passing the test.

So how can I do that ?

Comment: [`.find`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) returns an empty wrapper, **not** undefined, if the selector doesn't match anything.

Comment: So how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Well look at the example assertions in the docs, what do you think your case would be?

Comment: @AnuragMishra hey, did my answer solves your issue?

Comment: @wentjun No not yet. Can you please answer me this question ?

Comment: So.. You've tried what I have written, yeah? And what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to test for the existence of the `Typography` component, with the `id` of `showingRecords`. In that case, you should be using jest's [toHaveLength](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavelengthnumber) method.

```
test('should render a showing record section', () => {
  actionPlanProps["data"] = actionPlanData.data;
  const render = shallow(<ActionPlanCardComponent {...actionPlanProps} />);
  const typographyComponent = render.find("#showingRecords").first();
  expect(typographyComponent).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

This will test if a single `Typography` component is rendered.